# How to Install Visual studio 2015 with ASP.NET Core Template?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

Am little confused about Installing visual studio 2015 with ASP.NET core template? Firstly I install Visual Studio 15 and install Asp.net core 1.0.1 SDK but ASP.net core template missing in visual studio IDE.

After I'll search online and read multiple blogs and I install visual studio 2015 update 3 but there is also missing Asp.net core template again.

I got one solution i.e. After Installing SDK and visual studio 2015 update 3, **Install Asp.net core template pack** but I didn't find to is it the right way to install and used to develop asp.net core application.

Please share your help to solve this problem. Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you want to work with .NET Core it's better to download VS 2017. There are many templates like Angular, React comes with VS 2017.

Comment: firstly thank you for replay, yes i know visual studio 2017 is better way and there are many templates but asp.net core application developed in vs 2015 also that reason i want to know. how it work

Comment: You can use it with VS 2017, it supports 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 .NET Core projects.

Comment: If you've got anything for .NET Core in VS2015, it'll use the legacy project.json format, and only build with the preview SDK. I'd strongly advise you to update to VS2017.